# Jquery break line between data fields

Tags: jquery, line-breaks

I tried to break line between fields, but nothing i red on previous cases has worked for me : "
"    "\n"

```
$(function() {
    var body = $(document.body);
    for (var i = 0; i `enter code here`< data.length; i++) {
        $('<div></div').text(data[i].name + " " + data[i].age + " \n" + data[i].email).appendTo(body);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
        $(this).after('<br>');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<button>fix it up</button>
```

---

Of course, another way is just to use CSS:

CSS:

```
input{display:block;}
```

```css
input {display:block;}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: yes, using jquery to do what is better done using  CSS is a wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

Linebreaks are not relevant in HTML, you need to use the `<br/>` tag to achieve the desired affect.

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) MDN article.

Comment: yeah mostly,  line breaks work in the `<pre>` tag (and anything styled to be like a `<pre>` tag), and also in the `title` attribute.